# Cannot run query with more several subset in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have connected my Access-base to an MSSQL-database.

The query below works fine in Server Management Studio (SSMS), but when I try to run it in MS Access I get an error message.

Error: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'mainSet.FT_NR = subSet.FT_NR INNER JOIN ...

Does anyone know how I can get a query with two or more sub-queries to work in MS Access?

I know the query below can be simplified. The goal is to make more sub-sets work

```
SELECT DISTINCT mainSet.FT_NR
FROM
((SELECT FT_NR FROM tblTestdataH WHERE MILJO_ID=1) AS mainSet
INNER JOIN (SELECT FT_NR FROM tblTestdataH WHERE SYSTEM_ID=4) AS subSet ON mainSet.FT_NR = subSet.FT_NR
INNER JOIN (SELECT FT_NR FROM tblTestdataH WHERE SYSTEM_ID=1) AS subSet2 ON mainSet.FT_NR = subSet2.FT_NR)
ORDER BY mainSet.FT_NR
```

Comment: If i recall, the access joins have to be braceted, so `from ((a join b) join c)` i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT mainSet.FT_NR 
FROM 
((((SELECT FT_NR FROM tblTestdataH WHERE MILJO_ID=1) AS mainSet) 
INNER JOIN (SELECT FT_NR FROM tblTestdataH WHERE SYSTEM_ID=4) AS subSet ON subSet.FT_NR = mainSet.FT_NR) 
INNER JOIN (SELECT FT_NR FROM tblTestdataH WHERE SYSTEM_ID=1) AS subSet2 ON subSet2.FT_NR = mainSet.FT_NR)
ORDER BY mainSet.FT_NR
```

Comment: do keep in mind that sub query run access client side often can run VERY slow. So, I suggest you take the above query, save as a sql server view, and then link to that sql view. The result increase in performance will often be HUGE.